Maximizing $\operatorname{Tr}(W)$ subject to orthogonality and linear constraints
I have $n\times d$ matrices $X$, $Y$, $n\le d$, and I'm interested in finding orthogonal $W$ with $\operatorname{Tr}(W)$ as large as possible subject to that $XW=Y$.
Is there a way to do this which scales to $d=100, n=10$? Function orthogonalSolver[X,Y] below uses Minimize to solve this, but it gets slow for $d>4$, any tips?
Edit I was pointed to Julia's JuMP package which can handle larger instances here
ClearAll["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[1];

(* create random n,d problem instance *)
n = 2;
d = 4;
W0 = RandomVariate@CircularRealMatrixDistribution@d;
X = Orthogonalize@RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, d}];
Y = X . W0;

(* Closest orthogonal matrix to given matrix in Frobenius distance \
(see Higham's Polar ) *)
nearestOrthogonal[mat_] := 
  Module[{u, s, v}, {u, s, v} = SingularValueDecomposition[mat]; 
   u . v\[Transpose]];

(* Maximize Tr(W) subject to XW=Y and WW'=I constraints *)
orthogonalSolver[X_, Y_] := 
  Module[{W, ww, orthoCons, linearCons, d, n, matrixEqs},
   {n, d} = Dimensions[X];
   matrixEqs[A_, B_] := Flatten@MapThread[#1 == #2 &, {A, B}, 2];
   W = Array[ww, {d, d}];
   orthoCons = matrixEqs[W . W\[Transpose], IdentityMatrix@d];
   linearCons = matrixEqs[X . W, Y];
   W /. Last@Minimize[-Tr[W], orthoCons~Join~linearCons, Flatten@W]
   ];

(* solve instance *)
sol = orthogonalSolver[X, Y];
Print["Orthogonal constraint violation: ", 
  sol - nearestOrthogonal[sol] // Norm];
Print["Liner constraint violation: ", Y - X . sol // Norm];
Print["Objective: ", Tr[sol]]; (* 0.82896 *)

Related question on math.SE
Notebook

Came across SDP relaxation paper when orthogonal matrices are restricted to have rank $<n-d$

Do you have any bound on $n$, say something like $n<d/2$?

@A.Kato I was looking to do simulations with $n=10$ and $d=100$

I see. Thank you.

Inner products are invariant under the orthogonal transformation $W$, so are the the inner products among row vectors of $X$ and $Y$. This means that the two $n\times n$ matrices X.Transpose[X] and Y.Transpose[Y] must be the same. This is a very stringent condition. Can I really assume that your input data $X$ and $Y$ satisfy this condition?

You can assume that rows of $X$ are orthonormal and rows of $Y$ are orthonormal. The problem is that I rotate an orthogonal set of vectors $X$ by an unknown $W$ and I want to reconstruct $W$

1. Introduction: Outline of my approach
As you commented, let us assume that rows of $X$ are orthonormal and rows of $Y$ are orthonormal. Let $X_{aug}$ (rest. $Y_{aug}$) be an orthogonal $d\times d$ matrix whose first $n$ rows coincide with $X$ (resp. $Y$) and augmented by rectangular $(d-n)\times d$ block $U$ (resp. $V$):

If $W$ is the solution to the problem, then $X_{aug}W = Y_{aug}$ must hold
for some $U$ and $V$. If you also know $U$ and $V$, then $W = (X_{aug})^{-1} Y_{aug} = (X_{aug})^{T} Y_{aug}$. Moreover,
$$
  \mathrm{Tr} W = \mathrm{Tr} W^T = \mathrm{Tr} (Y_{aug})^{T} X_{aug}
= \mathrm{Tr} X_{aug} (Y_{aug})^{T} 
= \mathrm{Tr} (X Y^{T})  +  \mathrm{Tr} (U V^{T})
$$
So maximizing $\mathrm{Tr}(W)$ is equivalent to maximizing $\mathrm{Tr}(UV^T)$ .
For generic input data $X$ and $Y$, the all possible choices of $U$, $V$ are covered by the orbit of left multiplication $U \mapsto P_{1} U$, $V \mapsto P_{2} V$, where $P_{1}, P_{2}\in O(n-d)$. This changes the trace as
$$\mathrm{Tr} (UV^T) \mapsto \mathrm{Tr} (P_{1}UV^TP_{2}^T)= \mathrm{Tr} (P_{2}^TP_{1}UV^T)$$
So our problem boils down to finding $P =P_{2}^TP_{1} \in O(n-d)$
which maximize $\mathrm{Tr} (PA)$,
where $A$ is given by  $A = U V^T$.
In the next section, we will tackle this problem.
2. Given an invertible $k\times k$ matrix $A$, find the orthogonal matrix $P$ with $\mathrm{Tr}(PA)$ as large as possible.
We make an important assumption that $A$ is invertible. I will comment on this later in this section.
First important fact is the following
Lemma: Suppose $P$ is the maximizer of the problem above. Then $S:=AP$ is a symmetric matrix.
Proof) The key idea is to consider infinitesimal translations of $P$ in $O(k)$. Infinitesimal $O(k)$ rotations are generated by $k\times k$ skew-symmetric matrices. They span the $k(k-1)/2$ dimensional vector space $\frak{o}$$(k)$, the Lie algebra of $O(k)$. $\mathrm{Tr}(XY)$ is a non-degenerate bilinear form on the vector space of all $k\times k$ matrices. With respect to this pairing, the orthogonal complement to $\frak{o}$$(k)$ is nothing but the space of symmetric matrices. Therefore, the criticality of $\mathrm{Tr}(PA)=\mathrm{Tr}(AP)$ as a function of $P\in O(k)$ leads to the symmetry of the matrix $AP$ (or $PA$).   q.e.d.
N.B. Both $AP$ and $PA$ must be symmetric, but in general they do not coincide with each other.
So we need to find a symmetric matrix $S$ such that  $P = A^{-1}S$ is in $O(k)$. This condition can be rephrased as
$$P^T P=1 \iff (A^{-1}S)^{T} (A^{-1} S)=1\iff  S (A^{-1})^T A^{-1} S=1\iff S (AA^T)^{-1} S=1$$
where we used $S^T=S$ in the middle equivalence. Now, put $G=AA^T$. Then $G$ is positive definite symmetric matrix. So its matrix square root $\sqrt{G}$ is well defined. In fact, $S=\sqrt{G}$ solves the last equation. So the maximizer is given by $P=A^{-1}\sqrt{G}$.
MMA code looks something like:
ClearAll[maximizeTrPA];
maximizeTrPA[A_?SquareMatrixQ] := Module[{G, spec, Q, S, P},
   G = A . Transpose[A];
   {spec, Q} = Eigensystem[G];
   S = Transpose[Q] . DiagonalMatrix[Sqrt /@ spec] . Q;
   P = Inverse[A] . S;
   {Tr[P . A], P}
   ];

Let us test the code by a small example:
k = 4;
{P1, P2} = RandomVariate[CircularRealMatrixDistribution[k], 2];
diag = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, k];
A = P1 . DiagonalMatrix[diag] . P2;
correctAnswer = {Total[diag], Transpose[P1 . P2]}


Timing[ans = maximizeTrPA[A]]


We got the correct answer. If we adopted a straight-forward optimization code using NMaximize[ ] something like
ClearAll[usingNMaximize]; 
usingNMaximize[A_?SquareMatrixQ] := 
 Module[{k = Length[A], P, p, cons, ans},
  P = Array[p, {k, k}]; 
  cons = (# == 0 & /@ Flatten[P . Transpose[P] - IdentityMatrix[k]]); 
  ans = NMaximize[{Tr[P . A], cons}, Flatten[P]];
  {ans[[1]], P /. ans[[2]]}]; 

 Timing[ans2 = usingNMaximize[A]]


then it took 10000 times longer to get the same result.
Note: The case when $A$ is not invertible, some nontrivial rotations of $P$ which makes $\mathrm{Tr}(AP)$ invariant is possible. Therefore the solution is not unique any more. I haven't thought about this case thoroughly because this almost never happens in the situation of OP's question. The singular matrix case could be solved either by:

Perturbing $A \mapsto A + \varepsilon \mathbf{1}$ where $\varepsilon$ is a very small parameter,  or
Using PseudoInverse[] and taking suitable care of $\mathrm{ker}  A$, $\mathrm{ker} A^T$.

3. Solution to the Original Problem
Using the idea explained in Section 1, the final code would be:
ClearAll[orthogonalSolver];
orthogonalSolver[X_?MatrixQ, Y_?MatrixQ] := 
  Module[{eps = 0.00001, U, V, A, U1, P, tr, Xaug, Yaug},
   U = NullSpace[X];
   V = NullSpace[Y];
   A = U . Transpose[V];
   If[Abs[Det[A]]^(1/Length[A]) < eps, 
    Print["Warning: The input data are singular!"]];
   {tr, P} = maximizeTrPA[A];
   U1 = P . U;
   Xaug = Join[X, U1];
   Yaug = Join[Y, V];
   Transpose[Xaug] . Yaug
   ];

Let's find out if this code really solve the problem on a realistic scale.
n = 10;
d = 100;
X = Orthogonalize[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, d}]];
Y = Orthogonalize[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, d}]];
Timing[W = orthogonalSolver[X, Y]]


Confirm that the answer satisfies the constraints (up to numerical error)
Union[Chop[Flatten[#]]] & /@ {X.W-Y, Transpose[W].W-IdentityMatrix[d]}

(* {{0}, {0}} *)

Tr[W]

(* 82.6293 *) 

ArrayPlot /@ {X, Y, W}


Appendix: How to maximize $\mathrm{Tr} (QW)$ instead of $\mathrm{Tr}(W)$?
In response to the OP's new request, I put a code which finds an orthogonal matrix $W$ which realizes

$XW=Y$ and
maximizes $\operatorname{Tr}(QW)$.

The basic idea is almost the same, and we will use the same notation. First note that
$$
\mathrm{Tr} (QW) 
=\mathrm{Tr} (Q X_{aug}^{T} Y_{aug})
=\mathrm{Tr} (Y_{aug} Q X_{aug}^{T}).
$$
We want to maximize $\mathrm{Tr}(QW)$ using the freedom of $U\mapsto P_{1}U$ and $V\mapsto P_{2}V$.
Cut the $d\times d$ matrix $Z:=Y_{aug} Q X_{aug}^{T}$ into blocks as follows:

Here, $Z_{11}$ is $n\times n$, and $Z_{22}$ is $(d-n)\times (d-n)$.
We want to maximize $\mathrm{Tr} Z = \mathrm{Tr} (Z_{11}) + \mathrm{Tr} (Z_{22})$, but the above-mentioned freedom will affect only the second term:
$$\mathrm{Tr} (Z_{22}) \mapsto \mathrm{Tr}(P_{2}Z_{22}P_{1}^{T})=\mathrm{Tr}(P_{1}^{T}P_{2}Z_{22}).$$
Thus our new problem is essentially reduced to finding $P\in O(d-n)$ which maximizes $\mathrm{Tr} (P Z_{22})$.
Therefore, the code goes something like this:
ClearAll[orthogonalSolver2];
orthogonalSolver2[X_?MatrixQ, Y_?MatrixQ, Q_?SquareMatrixQ] := 
  Module[{eps = 0.00001, n, U, V, Xaug, Yaug, Z, A, P, V1, tr},
   n = Length[X];
   U = NullSpace[X];
   V = NullSpace[Y];
   Xaug = Join[X, U];
   Yaug = Join[Y, V];
   Z = Yaug . Q . Transpose[Xaug];
   A = Z[[n + 1 ;;, n + 1 ;;]];
   If[Abs[Det[A]]^(1/Length[A]) < eps, 
    Print["Warning: The input data are singular!"]];
   {tr, P} = maximizeTrPA[A];
   V1 = P . V;
   Yaug = Join[Y, V1];
   Transpose[Xaug] . Yaug
   ];

Test:
d = 100;
n = 10;
X = Orthogonalize[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, d}]];
Y = Orthogonalize[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, d}]];
Q = RandomVariate[CircularRealMatrixDistribution[d]];

Timing[W = orthogonalSolver2[X, Y, Q]; Tr[Q . W]]
(* {0.024866, 82.6252} *)

Union[Flatten[Chop[#]]]& /@ {X.W-Y, W.Transpose[W]-IdentityMatrix[d]}
(* {{0}, {0}} *)


Really nice answer.

Nice, works like a charm!

BTW, I just realized that in my application, I also need to maximize $Tr(QW)$ subject to  $XW=Y$, for user provided orthogonal matrix $Q$, is that a simple modification of your algorithm?

@DanielLichtblau Thank you (^^)

I'm glad I could help you. As for the maximizing $Tr(QW)$ case, I have some idea, but I don't have time right now. Please wait a moment.

@YaroslavBulatov I added Appendix which hopefully answers your request.

[Not a complete answer]
This will not scale to 100 but might provide a start. I set up the problem for 5x7, but it will scale beyond that at least. We enforce that m2 actually can be obtained as m1 times an orthogonal matrix.
{d1, d2} = {5, 7};
m1 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {d1, d2}];
mat = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {d2, d2}];
{qq, rr} = QRDecomposition[mat];
m2 = m1 . qq;

Now maximize for a matrix trace subject to it being orthogonal and recovering m2 when multiplied on the left by m1.
omat = Array[x, {d2, d2}];
Timing[{maxtr, vals} = 
   NMaximize[{Tr[omat], 
     Thread[Flatten[{m1 . omat - m2, 
         omat . Transpose[omat] - IdentityMatrix[d2]}] == 0]}, 
    Flatten[omat]];]

(* Out[138]= {12.7337, Null} *)

Check that the constraints are satisfied to reasonable precision.
mmm = omat /. vals;
Max[Abs[mmm . Transpose[mmm] - IdentityMatrix[d2]]]
Max[Abs[m1 . mmm - m2]]

(* Out[142]= 1.28556*10^-8

Out[143]= 4.44089*10^-16 *)

Check that the optimum at least is bigger than the trace of the matrix we originally used.
{maxtr, Tr[qq]}

(* Out[144]= {-0.319233, -1.7102} *)

For reference a 6x20 example using the same code took about 800 seconds.
--- edit ---
OK, I can do better using FindMinimum, subject to not necessarily quite reaching the optimum. When I first tried to use FindMinimum I got warning messages and putrid results that completely missed the constraints. It turns out this is because the equations were overdetermined (even if consistent). By removing the redundant lower triangular part of the orthogonality constraint we can get to an underdetermined system provided 2n<d.
Here I show a 5x25 matrix example. I first use the `NMaximize approach shown above.
Create the example:
{d1, d2} = {5, 25};
m1 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {d1, d2}];
mat = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {d2, d2}];
{qq, rr} = QRDecomposition[mat];
m2 = m1 . qq;

Set up the variables and constraints:
omat = Array[x, {d2, d2}];
c0 = omat . Transpose[omat] - IdentityMatrix[d2];
c1 = Table[c0[[i, j]], {i, d2}, {j, i, d2}];
c2 = m1 . omat - m2;
constraints = Thread[Flatten[{c1, c2}] == 0];

Optimize the trace:
Timing[{maxtr, vals} = 
   NMaximize[{Tr[omat], constraints}, Flatten[omat]];]

(* Out[343]= {2922.4, Null} *)

Check that the constraints are satisfied and find the max trace:
mmm = omat /. vals;
Max[Abs[mmm . Transpose[mmm] - IdentityMatrix[d2]]]
Max[Abs[m1 . mmm - m2]]
{maxtr, Tr[qq]}

(* Out[345]= 1.97591*10^-11

Out[346]= 7.77156*10^-16

Out[347]= {16.642, -1.81916} *)

Now redo using FindMinimum and repeat the checks.
Timing[{maxtrl, valsl} = 
   FindMaximum[{Tr[omat], constraints}, Flatten[omat]];]
mmml = omat /. valsl;
Max[Abs[mmml . Transpose[mmml] - IdentityMatrix[d2]]]
Max[Abs[m1 . mmml - m2]]
{maxtrl, Tr[qq]}

(* Out[362]= {20.4112, Null}

Out[364]= 1.36702*10^-8

Out[365]= 9.15934*10^-15

Out[366]= {16.4984, -1.81916} *)

So we do not get quite the same maximal trace, but close. And this shows promise for scaling further though still not necessarily to (10,100). For reference it handles (7,40) in 210 seconds and (8,60) in a bit under two hours on my desktop machine.
--- end edit ---
